# No one can write a review for a new app in Google Play Store if I goes from beta to prod

Tags: android, google-play

I used to have an application in beta on the google play store, I moved it from beta to production via google play developer console and all the users get this error and the review/mark is not saved.

Link to the app if it can help : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pasapas.eu.enigmes_pas_a_pas

The only thing I found about this error linked to the installation of the google play application but that cannot be the case for all users.
Just a clue I have: I succeeded in writing a review using the web interface of google play.

See screenshot:
[image: screenshot error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally understood why the problem appeared. If you have beta testers and then you promote an application to production, all your beta testers will be unable to write a review. To solve the issue just disable beta testing in the Google Play Console (I had Production and Beta testing at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

Its probably the cached meta data about the app installation, version and download channel. Try clearing the data for google play services and you should be good once it re-syncs.

That's the reason you can do it on web and not mobile.

In normal scenario, wait for a day or two will the meta gets updated and is in sync with google servers.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried to clean all the data earlier in the day with no success.   For the web interface I suceeded once but know I tried with some users and none of them can write a comment.

Comment: how long since you moved it from beta to prod? If it is less than a day I'd suggest giving the Google servers some time to replicate the change across all servers.

Comment: This morning 9:40 (8 hours ago), so I'll wait ! Thanks !

Comment: ah! like i said. give it some time. Tomorrow you should be good.

Comment: I was just editing my previous comment to say I'll wait then ! Thanks again !

Comment: I still have the issue 2 days later, but I think only people who first joined the beta testing have the issue. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

App must be installed on device.You cannot review app either you are addded as tester for app OR your email is not public means it belongs to work or school.

if not follow these steps-:
Open your device's main Settings app.
Tap Apps or Application manager (depending on your device, this may be different).
Tap Google Play Store.
Tap Storage.
Tap CLEAR CACHE > OK.
Tap CLEAR DATA > OK.
Tap the back arrow to go back to the main menu.
Select Downloads or Download Manager.
Tap CLEAR CACHE > OK.
Tap CLEAR DATA > OK.
Relaunch the app.

In case there are several accounts logged in at once, please check and log in one account at a time

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when promoting from a closed beta to production. Users could not rate the app, it said they could only give private feedback to the developer, and deleting the closed channel + email group didn't fix it. Even a user leaving the beta via the play store didn't fix it.

**I managed to fix it** (or work around it) by uploading a build to production with an incremented version code and nothing else.

According to Google Play support, beta builds are signed as such and this is what controls what the user sees in the play store listing. Builds promoted to production channel build are correctly not tagged as a beta build, BUT because they have the same version code as the beta builds already installed on user's phones, Google Play will not install the production-ified version automatically. So by bumping your version code straight into production, beta users' beta builds are replaced with production builds.